# Calling stored procedure in spring boot with Jpa returns empty objects

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I'm trying to fetch data from the store procedures in my spring boot rest api. The procedure call is successful but it return empty objects instead of returning any data. When I run those stored procedures in SQL Server those return the actual data.

Here are my stored procedure calls from the repository:

1. Get all stats without any param

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface GirdawariInfoAllDivisionsRepo extends 
    JpaRepository<GirdawariInfoOfAllDivisions, Long> {

    @Query(value = "GetGirdawariInfoOfAllDivisions", nativeQuery = true)
    List<GirdawariInfoOfAllDivisions> getAllDivisionsStatsList();
   ```

   }
2. Get Division's data based on division id

   ```
    @Repository
    public interface GirdawariInfoOfDistrictsByDivisionRepo extends 
    JpaRepository<GirdawariInfoOfDistrictsByDivision, Long> {

    @Query(value = "{CALL GetGirdawariInfoOfDistrictsByDivision(:Division_Id)};", nativeQuery = 
   true)
    List<GirdawariInfoOfDistrictsByDivision> getStatsBylDivisionsId(@Param("Division_Id") Long 
    Division_Id);
   ```

   }

The 1st one return 9 records in SQL Server but return 9 empty objects in `Jpa` like

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

The 2nd returns 5 records in SQL Server but return 5 empty objects in `Jpa` like

```
[{},{},{},{},{}]
```

The number of objects spring boot is returning is the same as expected but the problem is those are empty.

Please let me know if I have to add any other information.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It might pay to review your entity definitions for `GirdawariInfoOfDistrictsByDivision` and `GirdawariInfoOfDistrictsByDivision`. Check to see that the names of the properties exactly match the column names returned by the stored procedure, using `@Column(name="CorrectNameAndLetterCase")` decorators as required.

Comment: I'm not using `@Column` annotation but as for as I know spring boot throw exception if entity attributes do not match the column name. Anyway let me try `@Column` annotation

Comment: result is the same even with `@Column` annotation and I also have reviewed the column name that they match with the result of store procedure columns

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches to call stored procedures in spring-boot application.

Approach 1 – @NamedStoredProcedureQuery Annotation
Approach-2 @Procedure Annotation

Refer [here](https://springframework.guru/mysql-stored-procedures-with-spring-boot/). It has code example for both the approaches.